# can we index data from two different data sources in single data_config file via single DIH?

Tags: solr, solrj

Is it possible to index data from MySQL and text folder using **[DIH](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)**? I am using the following `data-config` file :

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource name="test1" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ACL"  user="root"
                password="" />
    <dataSource type="BinFileDataSource" />
    <document>
        <entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
                processor="FileListEntityProcessor" transformer="RegexTransformer"
                baseDir="/home/shah/ResearchTestData/TestScore3" fileName="\.(txt)|(pdf)|(docx)"
                onError="skip"
                recursive="true">
            <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
            <field column="fileLastModified" name="lastModified" />
            <field column="file" name="fileName" regex="(.txt)" replaceWith=""/>
            <entity name="documentImport"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text">
                <field column="text" name="Text" />         
            </entity>   
            <entity name="item" dataSource="test1" query="select PaperID,PID, Author  from ACL.Test where PaperID='${files.file}'">   
                <field column="PaperID" name="PaperID" />
                <field column="Author" name="Author" />
                <field column="PID" name="id" />               
            </entity>           
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

I want to index data into a single core through data import handler from two different data sources.

1. The first data source is a Mysql containing meta data of the text files .
2. The second data sources contains thousands of text  files.

I would like to index these different  data sources  in a single core using DIH.
The code is working, but the TikaEntityProcessor is not working?
Please where is the mistake in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure multiple data sources in a single configuration file](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Multiple_DataSources) and specify which data source an entity describes:

```
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-1" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://db1-host/dbname" user="db_username" password="db_password"/>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="ds-2" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://db2-host/dbname" user="db_username" password="db_password"/>
```

And then reference the data source in your entity:

```
<entity name="one" dataSource="ds-1" ...>
   ..
</entity>
<entity name="two" dataSource="ds-2" ...>
   ..
</entity>
```

My guess is that this works even for nested entities.

Comment: thanks @MatsLindh for reply, but my data sources are different. one is text files in one folder and second is mysql database. can i retrieve data from mysql database based on one of the text file field. see the code for information

Comment: <dataConfig>
<document>
<entity name="files" dataSource="null" rootEntity="false"
            processor="FileListEntityProcessor" transformer="RegexTransformer"
            baseDir="/home/shah/ResearchTestData/TestScore3" fileName="\.(txt)|(pdf)|(docx)"
         
            recursive="true">
                <field column="fileAbsolutePath" name="id" />
                <field column="fileSize" name="size" />
                <field column="fileLastModified" name="LastModified" />
                 <field column="file" name="fileName" regex="(.txt)" replaceWith=""/>

Comment: <entity
                    name="documentImport"
                    processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
                    url="${files.fileAbsolutePath}"
                    format="text">
<field column="text" name="Text" />
                </entity>
<dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ACL"  user="root"
                  password="" />

Comment: <entity name="item" query="select PaperID,PID, Author  from ACL.Test where PaperID=${files.file}">
            <field column="PaperID" name="PaperID" />
            <field column="Author" name="Author" />
<field column="PID" name="PID" />
       </entity>
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>

Comment: Please add code to your question and not to the comments and include any problems you have with the code and any error messages received.

Comment: thanks... please check the code, the question is updated accordingly where is the mistake?

Comment: You must wrap the entities inside each other if you want to perform the query based on field values from the other source.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ MatsLindh  now its working, but TikaEntityProcessor entity now doesn't index text to the Text field as show in the above code. where is the mistake in the TikaEntityProcessor entity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can index data from multiple heterogeneous data-sources in a single core by defining the entities in specific desired logical order.for information and code see: [why the tikaEntityProcesor does not index the Text field in the following data-config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46420735/why-the-tikaentityprocesor-does-not-index-the-text-field-in-the-following-data-c)